# Can i Get a draggable instance on a sortable event?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some draggables and a sortable container

when I drag that in to the sortable container I need to get the draggable instance,ie I need to find which draggable element I have dragged in to it.

Now the problem is, I have coded like, when I drag a draggable into the sortable area, it becomes the part of the sortable area.

There is no way to find out which draggable I have dragged in.

Can you guys please help.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of old, but I solved this by getting the event.target inside the drop function.

```
$('.my-drop-zone').droppable ({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    // item that was dragged
    var draggedItem = ui.draggable; //or ui.draggable.attr('id');
    // item it was dropped on
    var droppedOnItem = $(event.target); //or $(event.target).attr('id');
  }
});
```